# Why isn't this element added to the object?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am taking some random entry from MongoDB. I am just trying to append some additional data to it and send it to the front-end. I have done this several times, but for some reason cannot get it working.

```
var activity = {}
activity =  activities[Math.floor(Math.random() * activities.length)]
activity.fgg = "HIII" 
console.log(activity)
```

It doesn't append fgg? Why is that? However, if I make ANOTHER object and do 
`obj.activity = activity and obj.ff = "hii".` it DOES append but not in the format I want (obj inside obj). What is happening?

Output is:

```
{ __v: 0,
  activity: 'Go for a walk outside',
  name: 'Let your inner eagle SOUR!',
  _id: 56c21cc39686e94b7918bc58 }
```

Where is fgg?

Comment: maybe your `activities` var is empty?

Comment: nah it gives me name and activity and _id

Comment: Yep. Code is working for me if I sub in my own array of empty objects. Try doing a console log on activities before the line that appends `fgg`

Comment: Maybe activity is an object that have it's own toString, try `console.log(activity.toString)`

Comment: Oh its a mongo thing,let me try that!

Comment: Yup, its a mongo thing turns out you cannot modify mongos objects. Hmm, thats new

Comment: What solved MY problem was creating an objecting and inserting the values into that over lean()